# How to test convergence for $\sum^{\infty}_{n} \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^3}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

My try: using basic comparison. Since $\ln{n}\lt n^\frac13$ for large $n$, $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\gt \frac{1}{n^\frac13}$. Since $\sum^{\infty}_{n} \frac{1}{(n^\frac13)^3}$ diverges, so $\sum^{\infty}_{n} \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^3}$ diverges. Is my solution correct?

Comment: I'd say yes.${}$

Comment: Yes $\times 2$.

Comment: What is the sub-indices? $n$?

Comment: Looks good, although one might challenge you to prove that $\ln n<n^{1/3}$. But if you can prove that, it's solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the comparison test states the following:

Suppose that we have two series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ with $a_n,b_n\geq 0$ for all n and $a_n\leq b_n$ for all n.

If  $\sum a_n$ is divergent, then so is  $\sum b_n$. So, while you do have the right conclusion, you could run into a problem with this comparison.

However, another way to test convergence is the integral test: $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{(\ln(x))^3}dx$. This integral does not converge so we are good.